# tmp folder create in s3 bucket [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/plain_file/7A50-99D2-24D9-42BF.tar': FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, tmp

I am working on lambda and using s3 bucket and I create tmp folder.
but it throw error **[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/plain_file/7A50-99D2-24D9-42BF.tar': FileNotFoundError**

```
image_path = '/tmp/' + image_name
plain_file = '/tmp/plain_file/' + job_key
cipher_file = '/tmp/cipher_file/' + job_key

tar = tarfile.open(plain_file, "w")
        tar.add(image_path)
        tar.close()
```

what should I change for properly working

Comment: Your sample code is not showing anything to do with S3. It is simply saying that there is no file with the name you have used. What makes you think there is a file with that name in the `/tmp/plain_file/` directory?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein there is no file in /tmp/plain_file/ directory because i create that file and put that file in this directory.
because locally everything is working well because I am using windows..so I have to give path locally .. but remotely /tmp/ folder i have to create.
so i am asking that the way i am defining tmp path is it True?

Comment: or i remove one / .. this is true?
image_path = '/tmp/' + image_name
plain_file = 'tmp/plain_file/' + job_key
cipher_file = 'tmp/cipher_file/' + job_key

Comment: If you wish to use a `plain_file` directory within `/tmp`, you will need to create it before using it. Or, simply store the files in `/tmp` with no sub-directory (but use different filenames or extensions so they don't clash).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein but i want to work it remotely

Comment: can i use os.makedirs ?

Comment: Yes. You would use: `os.mkdir('/tmp/plain_file')`